Beginners question: Inner product used to denote a straight line?
I found this in my notes about differential geometry.
Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The straight line $\langle p,q \rangle$ is the curve of the following regular smooth curves:
$\beta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n}: t \mapsto (1-t)*p +t*q$.
I am confused since for me the inner product of two vectors is a single number so I don't understand what the author means with "the straight line $\langle p,q \rangle$".

It's just notation for the (oriented) straight line through $p$ and $q$. Same symbol as the inner product, but with a different meaning.

@anomaly thank you!!!
